# Why does the wind close doors?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, flow, perception

Assume you have two rooms, both with holes in the wall (more commonly known as *open windows*), which connect each room to the exterior. The two rooms are connected, but the connection can be closed by a device commonly known as *door*.
Why does the door always shut?

Or isn't it the case that it always shuts, but it is rather a psychological effect that we don't pay attention to an open door before it slams shut?

Comment: It depends on orientation of door opening wrt dominant external pressure gradient. It is possible the both, shutting the door and  needed  force to close the doors against air pressure.

Comment: If the door doesn't latch in the closed position you would expect it to swing left and right depending on the currents. If there is a latch, then the ultimate state is always closed, because once closed it cannot open again.